# How to place variadic template arguments into an array?

Tags: c++

I want to have a variable number of arguments to a function and inside that function I want to place them into an array. I tried to use a fold expression for this because I didn't understand what they did. I thought they just simply expanded the arguments with a comma in between:

```
template <typename ... var_args_t>
void putArgumentsToArray(var_args_t&& ... values)
{
    constexpr int num_args = sizeof ... (var_args_t);

    int values_array[num_args] = {

        (values, ...)
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < num_args; ++i)
        std::cout << values_array[i] << "\n";
    /* PRINTS [6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]*/

}


int main()
{
    putArgumentsToArray(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
}
```

The end result is that the array is only initialised with one value(6), because all six arguments are evaluated as expressions, however the comma operator works so that only the last argument is returned. So the array has only one initialiser.

I know I can use a std::vector or a loop, but it would be really nice and clean if I could do this directly into the array initialiser.

Answer (score 1):

You have confused the syntax a bit. You wished parentheses on other places

```
int values_array[num_args] = {
    (values)...
};
```

or the same but without parentheses

```
int values_array[num_args] = {
    values...
};
```

`values...` expands to

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
```

Whereas `(values, ...)` expands to the comma operator in the parentheses

```
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
```

that returns the single 6, the value of the last operand of the comma operator.

Comment: @zebrafish And do use `std::array<int, num_args>`.

Comment: Can I expand a member of each argument into the array? Like int my_array[num_args] = { var_args.id ... };  ?

Comment: Why not. Have you tried and seen issues?